# QGIS rank by category

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I have a dataset with two attributes:

`Attribute 1`: A , B, C

`Attribute 2`: 1, 2, 3, 4

I want to rank `Attribute 2` but with a separate rank for each value in `Attribute 1`.

I already did the ranking by using this function:

```sql
array_find(
    array_sort(
        array_agg( "Attribute 2" ), 
         true
    ),
    "Attribute 2" 
) + 1
```

The result is a ranking of all values. Now I need an extension for separate ranking based on `Attribute 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `group_by` parameter to `array_agg`:

```sql
array_find(
    array_sort(
        array_agg("Attribute 2", group_by:="Attribute 1"), 
        true
    ),
    "Attribute 2" 
) + 1
```